# Windows open ports command line

Tags: windows, port

Is there any way to see open ports of *windows* in a specific range using command line?

For example i want to see open ports in range 1-1024.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will list all open (in use) ports.

```
netstat -na
```

Filtering is a bit harder. This script takes two ports as the (inclusive) range of local ports to filter for.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET STARTPORT=%1
SET ENDPORT=%2

FOR /F "delims=|" %%l IN ('netstat -na') DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=2" %%a IN ("%%l") DO (
        REM IPv6 uses colons, too.
    SET "LOCAL=%%~a"
    SET "LOCAL=!LOCAL:*]=0!"
        FOR /F "delims=: tokens=2" %%p IN ("!LOCAL!") DO (
            IF %%p LEQ %ENDPORT% ( IF %%p GEQ %STARTPORT% ( @ECHO %%l ) )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. How do i use this script?I saved it as batch file but when i open it nothing happens?

Comment: The `%1` and `%2` are command-line parameters, namely the lower and upper port numbers.